# Leadbolt sdk banner ads not showing

Tags: android, leadbolt

My `Admob` account was recently closed abruptly without any warning. So I am trying to integrate the `Leadbolt` ad library, but the ads are not showing. I am only trying to add Banners at the bottom of the page. Here is what I have so far:

Code in my `Activtiy.onCreate()`

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ... other stuff...
        // private AdController ad; (This is defined as a class variablein the activity)
        ad = new AdController(this, "my_section_id"); // my_section_id from the leadbolt page where I configured the banner ad. 
        ad.loadAd();
```

Code in my `Activity.onDestroy()`

```
ad.destroyAd(); 
super.onDestroy();
```

The configuration page shows everything correctly:

[image]

I have added the all the permissions in the `Manifest` file as well. As per the [Doumentation](http://www.leadbolt.com/docs/LeadBolt_android_sdk_guide.pdf), I could not find any xml/layout addition that is needed.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
ad.loadStartAd("Audio id", "re-engagement id");
```